# How can we have a perfect square image without distortion

Tags: html, css, image, shapes

There is a scenario, where I need to show profile image in a perfect square shape. At the moment don't have control over the code but the application can be controlled through css. Is there anyway to do this directly on img element using css without distorting or stretching the image?  Placing the img inside div option is not feasible due to source restrictions.

Comment: @kiner_shah both of those solutions rely on a parent element and op said *"Is there anyway to do this directly on img element using css without distorting or stretching the image ? Placing the img inside div option is not feasible due to source restrictions."*

Comment: @MichaelCoker, got it! Removed the link!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `object-fit` in css.

```css
img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
```